# jQuery function to ran on each slide

Tags: jquery, slider, jquery-events

I have a "Swiper Slide" slider and I would like to have a certain function ran on each slide.

Here is a link with the slider demo (mine is same in terms of coding):

http://idangero.us/swiper

I want to identify the event for jQuery to ran  function when slider goes to another slide (and when user force it to go to another slide).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the custom event `onSlideChangeStart` or `onSlideChangeEnd` of this plugin to call your function like this for example:

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  onSlideChangeStart: function(swiper) {
    //call your function here
  },
  onSlideChangeEnd: function(swiper) {
    //or here
  }
});
```

You can read more about this in the official **[documentation](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#.WGK9TVV97IU)**.

Comment: Thanks, and if I use $(this) selector, which element will I get??

Comment: Or I can even use $('.active') right?? As, slider gives active slide "active" class

Comment: @user1584043 You can get the index of the current slide like `console.log(swiper.activeIndex);` if that is what you need, and yes, you should be able to use `$('.active')` or `$('.slide-active')` also.